# Experimental Design

Tags: experiment-design, factor-analysis

Given a coach wants to study the effect of practice techniques on the rate at which his students are able to learn new skills in soccer. He chooses 4 different drills (shooting, passing, dribbling, endurance) to use for the experiment. The amount of practice is important, so he will ask his players to train either 30 mins, 1 hour or 2 hours per day. He also wants to know if watching pro soccer at home is helpful, so he will have some players watch pro soccer each day in addition to practicing (while the others will only practice, without watching pro soccer). After one month, each player will perform a test of skills and he will assign a grade out of 100 to the skill level of each player. He has a group of 30 players to use for this experiment: 15 of them are highly skilled, the other 15 are intermediately skilled.

Given the experimental design what is the factor(s) and levels in this experiment and how would you apply blocking, randomization and replication to this experiment?

I am not sure the differences between factors and their levels, can anyone explain what they would be for the experiment and explain how to go about applying blocking, randomization and replication to this experiment?

Comment: To get you started.  This situation a factor is the variable which is varied for the experiment.  So Amount of Practice and Watching Professionals are examples of a factor.  The levels are the values each factor takes.  So for practice time the levels are 0.5, 1 or 2 hours/day.  For your other questions, best to refer to your notes or Google it.

Comment: Okay Dave thanks for your help, why is the 4 different drills not a factor?

Comment: Good question, it depends on how one interprets the question.  They could be the output or they could be factors if the players are assigned to different skills to master.

Comment: Okay what if the players are being tested on how well they perform those drills? Then are they considered factors?

Comment: The player’s skill level is a factor.  Each player is different there not a very controllable variable.  
The player themselves are more or less are the test subjects.  That is where the blocking, randomization and replication comes into play.